# Regular expression to find one or more than one substring inside big string

Tags: ruby, regex

Hi i want regular expression to find one or more than one substrings inside big string match some criteria like.

```
   "I have done my best to document all the [switches] and characters that I can  locate.Regular expressions [allow] you to group like [parts] of the substring into"
```

the result should be like these substrings

```
         switches,allow,parts
```

and in this case

```
      "I have done my best to document all the [switches] and character.
```

result should be the only "switches"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need String#scan:

```
str = "I have done my best to document all the [switches] and characters that I can  locate.Regular expressions [allow] you to group like [parts] of the substring into"
str.scan /\[.+?\]/   # => ["[switches]", "[allow]", "[parts]"]
# or use lookahead and lookbehind pattern
str.scan /(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/ # => ["switches", "allow", "parts"]
```

The Regexp will match any chars between '[' and ']'. The pattern .+? means NOT do this thing greedy. When a "]" is matched, this part is over. Otherwise, if we use [.*] , the matching will return [switches......parts].

Comment: can i get values like this using regex only? ["switches", "allow", "parts"]. with out calling any string function not like this ["[switches]", "[allow]", "[parts]"]